# React incorrect state passed to child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React funcion component with states initialized as below

```
const [selectedSection, setSelectedSection] = useState('section1');
const [section, setSection] = useState({
    section1: false,
    section2: false,
    section3: false
});
```

Now, on click/change of the section links, I invoke below;

```
const onSectionChange = (id) => {
    setSelectedSection(id);
}

useEffect(() => {
    // Below seems incorrect way of doing... Not sure what is the right way ??
    setSection({
        section1: false,
        section2: false,
        section3: false
    });
    setSection({...section, [selectedSection]: true});
}, [selectedSection]);
```

I want to pass the new selected section to my child component as below

```
<MyChildComponent section={section}>
```

For some reason, the correct state is not passed to MyChildComponent. I assume I am not setting setSection properly in my useEffect. What is the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 4):

From what you've described here. I think you can achieve your desired results without the use of two states, as I think it's redundant to use two states for the same thing.

```
const defaultSessions = {
    section1: false,
    section2: false,
    section3: false
}

const [section, setSection] = useState({...defaultSessions, section1: true});

// Now, on click/change of the section links, I invoke below;
const onSectionChange = (id) => {
    setSection(prev => ({...defaultSessions, [id]: true}))
}

<button onClick={() => onSectionChange('section1')} > Section 1 </button>
<button onClick={() => onSectionChange('section2')} > Section 2 </button>
<button onClick={() => onSectionChange('section3')} > Section 3 </button>
```

You should not use useEffect hooks if not needed, as they will create unnecessary re-renders. As for the above code, when you click the link button, it will call the `onSectionChange` with the respective `id`. We can then directly change the main state, and turn the selected link value to `true`.

Note that it is a good practice to use the above method to update a state, as we will get the current state value in the `prev` variable, which we can easily update and set the state to the update value.

Also you were using `setState` one after other in the same function. Note that it won't work like that. You should only set the state once in a scope.

Comment: Thanks...seems like some syntax error on     setSection(prev => {...prev, [id]: true})

Comment: @copenndthagen Please check again. There was a parenthesis missing

Comment: Actually even now, same issue...so when I move from section1 to section2, section2 becomes true, but even section1 is remaining true (section1 should be false when I go to section2)

Comment: Also, I need by default (on page load), section1 to be true

Comment: @copenndthagen, Please check now, this code will select section1 by default and work as you require

Comment: Thanks...yeah, this seems to be working...though just testing some more scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could think of it in a differnt way:

You've marked the selected section, which means that the other sections are always false, so you don't need to mark the other sections as false, just use it directly.

Here is an example:

```js
const mockSection = [
    {
        id: 'section1'
    },
    {
        id: 'section2'
    },
    {
        id: 'section3'
    },
    {
        id: 'section4'
    }
]

const [selectedSection, setSelectedSection] = useState('section1');

const onSectionChange = (id) => {
    setSelectedSection(id);
}

// ex.1
const UlComponent = <ul>
    {
        mockSection.map( section => 
            <li class={section.id === selectedSection ? 'style-on':''} onClick="onSectionChange(section.id)">some thing</li>
        )
    }
</ul>

// ex.2
const CheckComponent = <div>
    {
        mockSection.map( section => 
            <input type="checkbox" checked={section.id === selectedSection} onClick="onSectionChange(section.id)" />
        )
    }
</div>
```

This is the same for the child, just pass `selectedSection`.
Logic first, Code last.

```
<MyChildComponent selectedSection={selectedSection}></MyChildComponent>
```

Comment: This is what I would do, but this answer could be improved with a small code example.

Answer (score 0):

No Need to use two setState and useEffect, you can achieve this using one setState only.

```
     const defaultSection = {
       section1:false,
       section2:false,
       section3:false,
     }
```

define this constant then you can modify the onSectionChange function.

```
     const onSectionChange = (id) => {
       setSection({
         ...defaultSection,
        [id]: true
    })
}
```